# How to create complex JSON config maps in q?

Tags: json, kdb

Is there a good way in q to input somewhat large complicated nested dictionaries which represent/will be converted to json? I'm trying to control the echarts javascript library which basically just renders charts based on json config options. What I'm doing now is:

```
opt.title.text:"my chart"
opt.xAxis.data:til 100
opt.series.data:100?5
opt.series.type:`line
toClient[opt] /serializes and sends to browser
```

but is there an obvious way to get rid of the intermediate assignment? Is making a function to take key-path/value pairs and turn them into a dictionary the way to go or is there a better way to go about this?

Or is this something that should be avoided in q, and instead just manually set write q to set specific options and handle the json object map in the javascript client?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is really what you are looking for, but you can create the nested dictionary structure directly if that's what you're after?

```
q)`title`xAxis`series!(enlist[`text]!enlist"my chart";enlist[`data]!enlist til 100;`data`type!(100?5;`line))
title | (,`text)!,"my chart"
xAxis | (,`data)!,0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 ..
series| `data`type!(0 1 1 3 3 3 2 2 4 1 3 3 1 4 0 4 4 4 2 4 3 3 4 0 4 0 0 1 0..
```

Comment: I understand that this is possible but doesn't seem easy to read/write if I want to be able to flexibly control and tweak the chart from a q prompt. I was more wondering if there are alternative methods or idioms to end up with these nested maps, or if this part of the program is best kept to the javascript side.

Comment: My current thinking is to write a function that takes a list of consecutive "keypath" followed by value pairs, like 
    ```nestmap[(`title`text;"my chart";`xAxis`data;til 100;`series`data;100?5;`series`data`type;`line)]```
 and then expands that into the nested dictionary. But this is slightly involved and I'm not sure if this is "un-q-like" and if I should be thinking about the problem differently

Comment: You will have to make some helper functions (like the one you mentioned) to make it more readable and easy for users. If you want to modify or access some parts of nested dictionary  then check 'apply' operator, that makes it simple.

Also if this is not that required in Q and could be moved to javascript then check that option as well because javascript has couple of libraries for Json handling which might make it simpler than Q.